# override Makefile goal

Tags: makefile

The situation is as follow: We use the common perforce source control system. Each time we build, we sync up the latest code and run the Makefile from perforce (let's call it the main Makefile). Is there away to override the goal inside the main Makefile with very minor changes to it, so that we can insert some customized actions on the same goal.

For example, the main Makefile looks like this

```
all:
     echo "main Makefile actions"
```

How can we insert our customized actions into the same rule, by including a personal `Makefile.personal`

```
all:
     echo "my actions"
```

The expected result is that when we do `make all`, the actions which are carried out are both

```
echo "main Makefile actions"
echo "my actions"
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: Thank everyone for your answers! Maxim Yegorushkin's approach does minimal changes to the Makefile on perforce, so I select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least couple of ways:

1) Have another target with your custom actions in another makefile that includes the main makefile:

```
# my_makefile.mk
include Makefile   

my_custom_actions : all
    echo "my actions"

$ make -f my_makefile.mk my_custom_actions
```

2) Use [double colon rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon) in the main Makefile so that another makefile can add actions to existing targets.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to `make` instead of `make all`, you can do this:

main Makefile:

```
include Makefile.personal

all:
     echo "main Makefile actions"
```

Makefile.personal:

```
my_all: all
     echo "my actions"
```

If you want to `make all`, but you don't care about the order of the two sets of actions, you can do this:

main Makefile:

```
include Makefile.personal

all:
     echo "main Makefile actions"
```

Makefile.personal:

```
my_all:
     echo "my actions"

all: my_all
```

I you want to `make all` and you *do* care about the order, there are a few different ways to do it, none pretty.